# Cannot be cast to class org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JCircuitBreaker

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, resilience4j

I was using Spring Boot 2.4 with Gradle.

Here is how I've defined my dependency:

```
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'
```

It was working fine, but when I add:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.circuitbreaker.TraceCircuitBreaker cannot be cast to class org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JCircuitBreaker (org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.circuitbreaker.TraceCircuitBreaker and org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JCircuitBreaker are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a7735aed.create(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same problem just recently. here is how I fixed the problem:

I was using an Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory to create the CircuitBreaker.

```
@Autowired
private Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory;

...

CircuitBreaker checkStockWithCircutBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("inventory");
```

this did not work once I added the spring-cloud-starter-sleuth dependency. use the abstract class CircuitBreakerFactory so that Spring automatically injects the proper CircuitBreakerFactory instance available

```
@Autowired
private CircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory;

...

CircuitBreaker checkStockWithCircutBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("inventory");
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Spring Cloud Sleuth documentation, you have to dissable sleuth circuit breaker. It can just be solved adding the following property in the application.properties: `spring.seuth.circuitbreaker.enabled=false`

The documentation link is the following: [Spring Cloud Sleuth documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-circuitbreaker-integration)